# Directive to Directive Communication with different modules

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to find out how to communicate between two directives in different modules. I am able to make it work if it is in the same module. Please check the fiddle here. Anyone can help?
http://jsfiddle.net/3wxy2m7m/1/

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <basket apple orange>Roll over me and check the console!</basket>
</body>

var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.directive("basket", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.content = [];

      this.addApple = function() {
        $scope.content.push("apple");
      };

      this.addOrange = function() {
        $scope.content.push("orange");
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.bind("mouseenter", function() {
        console.log(scope.content);
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive("apple", function() {
  return {
    require: "basket",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, basketCtrl) {
      basketCtrl.addApple();
    }
  };
});

var app2 = angular.module("MyApp2", ['MyApp']);
app2.directive("orange", function() {

  return {
    require: "basket",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, basketCtrl) {
      basketCtrl.addOrange();
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your module dependencies 
from

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
var app2 = angular.module("MyApp2", ['MyApp']);
```

to

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['MyApp2']);
var app2 = angular.module("MyApp2", []);
```

Comment: small correction, it should be => var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['MyApp2']);